# Webscraping using Scrapy, where is the output?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to build a spider, that gathers information regarding startups. Therefore I wrote a Python script with scrapy that should access the website and store the information in a dictionary. I think the code should work from a logik point of view, but somehow I do not get any output. My code:

```
import scrapy


class StartupsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'startups'
    #name of the spider

    allowed_domains = ['www.bmwk.de/Navigation/DE/InvestDB/INVEST-DB_Liste/investdb.html']
    #list of allowed domains

    start_urls = ['https://bmwk.de/Navigation/DE/InvestDB/INVEST-DB_Liste/investdb.html']
    #starting url

    def parse(self, response):
        
        startups = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"card-link-overlay")]/@href').getall()
        #parse initial start URL for the specific startup URL

        for startup in startups:
            
            absolute_url =  response.urljoin(startup)

            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_startup)
            #parse the actual startup information

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[@class ="pagination-link"]/@href').get()
        #link to next page
        
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        #go through all pages on start URL
        yield scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page_url)
    
    def parse_startup(self, response):
    #get information regarding startup
        startup_name = response.css('h1::text').get()
        startup_hompage = response.xpath('//*[@class="document-info-item"]/a/@href').get()
        startup_description = response.css('div.document-info-item::text')[16].get()
        branche = response.css('div.document-info-item::text')[4].get()
        founded = response.xpath('//*[@class="date"]/text()')[0].getall()
        employees = response.css('div.document-info-item::text')[9].get()
        capital = response.css('div.document-info-item::text')[11].get()
        applied_for_invest = response.xpath('//*[@class="date"]/text()')[1].getall()

        contact_name = response.css('p.card-title-subtitle::text').get()
        contact_phone = response.css('p.tel > span::text').get()
        contact_mail = response.xpath('//*[@class ="person-contact"]/p/a/span/text()').get()
        contact_address_street = response.xpath('//*[@class ="adr"]/text()').get()
        contact_address_plz = response.xpath('//*[@class ="locality"]/text()').getall()
        contact_state = response.xpath('//*[@class ="country-name"]/text()').get()

        yield{'Startup':startup_name,
              'Homepage': startup_hompage,
              'Description': startup_description,
              'Branche': branche,
              'Gründungsdatum': founded,
              'Anzahl Mitarbeiter':employees,
              'Kapital Bedarf':capital,
              'Datum des Förderbescheids':applied_for_invest,
              'Contact': contact_name,
              'Telefon':contact_phone,
              'E-Mail':contact_mail,
              'Adresse': contact_address_street + contact_address_plz + contact_state}
```

Comment: How do you run the spider?

Comment: I am running it from the command prompt using scrapy crawl and the name of the spider.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're not getting output because your `allowed_domains` is wrong.
2. In the last line (`Adresse`), you're trying to concatenate `list` and `str` types so you'll get an error.
3. Your pagination link is wrong, in the first page you're getting the next page, and in the second page you're getting the previous page.
4. You're not doing any error checking. In some pages you're getting `None` for some of the values and you're trying to get their i'th character which results in an error.

I fixed 1, 2, and 3. But you'll need to fix number 4 yourself.

```py
import scrapy


class StartupsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # name of the spider
    name = 'startups'

    # list of allowed domains
    allowed_domains = ['bmwk.de']

    # starting url
    start_urls = ['https://bmwk.de/Navigation/DE/InvestDB/INVEST-DB_Liste/investdb.html']
    
    def parse(self, response):
        # parse initial start URL for the specific startup URL
        startups = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"card-link-overlay")]/@href').getall()

        for startup in startups:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(startup)

            # parse the actual startup information
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_startup)

        # link to next page
        next_page_url = response.xpath('(//*[@class ="pagination-link"])[last()]/@href').get()
        if next_page_url:
            # go through all pages on start URL
            absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page_url)

    def parse_startup(self, response):
        # get information regarding startup
        startup_name = response.css('h1::text').get()
        startup_hompage = response.xpath('//*[@class="document-info-item"]/a/@href').get()
        # for example for some of the pages you'll get an error here:
        startup_description = response.css('div.document-info-item::text')[16].get()
        branche = response.css('div.document-info-item::text')[4].get()
        founded = response.xpath('//*[@class="date"]/text()')[0].getall()
        employees = response.css('div.document-info-item::text')[9].get()
        capital = response.css('div.document-info-item::text')[11].get()
        applied_for_invest = response.xpath('//*[@class="date"]/text()')[1].getall()

        contact_name = response.css('p.card-title-subtitle::text').get()
        contact_phone = response.css('p.tel > span::text').get()
        contact_mail = response.xpath('//*[@class ="person-contact"]/p/a/span/text()').get()
        Adresse = ' '.join(response.xpath('//*[@class ="address"]//text()').getall())

        yield {'Startup': startup_name,
               'Homepage': startup_hompage,
               'Description': startup_description,
               'Branche': branche,
               'Gründungsdatum': founded,
               'Anzahl Mitarbeiter': employees,
               'Kapital Bedarf': capital,
               'Datum des Förderbescheids': applied_for_invest,
               'Contact': contact_name,
               'Telefon': contact_phone,
               'E-Mail': contact_mail,
               'Adresse': Adresse}
```

Comment: nice catch... I didn't even notice that

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I guessed that there might be an erroer with pagination, because on the website there is no "next"  button I could search for. I thought it might end up in some sort of endless loop. What exactly do you mean by error checking? Should I try and implement some try, except statement?

Comment: You can do this without try except. See the comment I wrote in `parse_startup`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run in prompt:
scrapy crawl  -o filename.(json or csv)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).